# Why does System.Decimal ignore checked/unchecked context

Tags: c#, .net

I just stumbled into a `System.Decimal` oddity once more and seek an explaination.

When casting a value of type `System.Decimal` to some other type (i. e. `System.Int32`) the [`checked` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) and the [`-checked` compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option) seem to be ignored.

I've created the following test to demonstrate the situation:

```
public class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestChecked()
    {
        int max = int.MaxValue;

        // Expected if compiled without the -checked compiler option or with -checked-
        Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, (int)(1L + max));

        // Unexpected
        // this would fail
        //Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, (int)(1M + max));
        // this succeeds
        Assert.Throws<OverflowException>(() => { int i = (int)(1M + max); });


        // Expected independent of the -checked compiler option as we explicitly set the context
        Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, unchecked((int)(1L + max)));

        // Unexpected
        // this would fail
        //Assert.Equal(int.MinValue, unchecked((int)(1M + max)));
        // this succeeds
        Assert.Throws<OverflowException>(() => { int i = unchecked((int)(1M + max)); });


        // Expected independent of the -checked compiler option as we explicitly set the context
        Assert.Throws<OverflowException>(() => { int i = checked((int)(1L + max)); });

        // Expected independent of the -checked compiler option as we explicitly set the context
        Assert.Throws<OverflowException>(() => { int i = checked((int)(1M + max)); });
    }
}
```

All my research unitl now didn't lead to a proper explaination for this phenomenon or even some [misinformation claiming that it should work](https://books.google.de/books?id=9fAmRzYaxFgC&lpg=PT46&ots=_nTzdFnuRf&dq=checked%20decimal%20cookbook&hl=de&pg=PT46#v=onepage&q=checked%20decimal%20cookbook&f=false).
My research already included the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-checked-and-unchecked-operators)

Is there anybody out there who can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `checked` context relates to IL emitted from your code - it basically changes the opcode used for those math operations from the unchecked version to the checked version. It can't do that for `decimal` because `decimal` *isn't a primitive*, and has no direct opcodes: all the arithmetic operations are pre-built in custom operators, exactly like they would be if you added your own `struct MyType` and added operators for it. So: it would all depend on whether the custom operators defined by `decimal` choose to detect and throw `OverflowException` or not, *in that code*. Which you don't control, and can't influence in your build.

It is the `decimal` type that provides the `decimal` <===> `int` conversions. By the time it gets back to *your* code - where the `checked` keyword could have an effect - it is already either an `int` or an exception has been thrown.

The C# custom operator support does not extend to allowing you to add separate checked / unchecked operator implementations, sadly.

Comment: what will be the default for an operation? `checked` or `unchecked`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj the default is: whatever the build told the default to be. The "default default" (if you see what I mean...) is "unchecked". If you're using Visual Studio, this setting is in the "Advanced..." button on the "Build" tab of project properties, labelled "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow". If you use the `checked` or `unchecked` keywords around a region of C#: that wins over everything else. It is the `<CheckForOverflowUnderflow>` key in a csproj file, or `/checked` when using `csc`

Answer (score 2):

C# specification (section 12.7.14 The checked and unchecked operators) contains list of affected operators and statements. Operators in your test aren't in the list:

> The following operations are affected by the overflow checking context established by the `checked` and
>   `unchecked` operators and statements:
>
> - The predefined `++` and `--` operators (§12.7.10 and §12.8.6), when the operand is of an integral or enumtype.
> - The predefined `-` unary operator (§12.8.3), when the operand is of an integral type.
> - The predefined `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` binary operators (§12.9), when both operands are of integral or enumtypes.
> - Explicit numeric conversions (§11.3.2) from one integral or enumtype to another integral or enumtype, or from `float` or `double` to an integral or enumtype.

Comment: You're right - I've been there and didn't see it: "Explicit numeric conversions (§11.3.2) from one **integral or enumtype to another integral or enumtype, or from float or double to an integral or enumtype**" which doesn't include `decimal`. Still I prefer @marc-gravells answer as it includes the reason behind this, which was the point of my question.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR offers IL instructions for simple arithmetic operations like `add` (addition), `sub`(subtraction), `mul`(multiplication), `div`(division).

For example lets take an `add` instruction, which adds two values together. The `add` instruction performs no overflow checking, but there is instruction called `add.ovf`, which also adds two values together, but will throw an `OverflowException` if an overflow occurs.

So when you are using `checked` operator, statement or compiler switch, it will use *"overflow checking"* version of `add` instruction (`add.ovf`).

Remember this only works for a *"Primitive Types"*.

**But** with `decimal`s things are little different. `decimal` type is not considered as a primitive type by CLR (although programming languages like c# or visual basic does), which means that CLR does not have IL instructions that know how to manipulate `decimal` value. If you look for a `decimal` type in .NET Framework SDK Documantation or on [Source Code in ReferenceSources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,1b2858baf311cbf9) - you will notice, that there is methods called `Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, etc..` and operator overload methods for `+, -, *, /, etc`.

When you compile code that uses `decimal`, the compiler will generate code to call `decimal` members to perform the actual operation. Also, because there are no IL instructions for manipulating `decimal` values, the `checked/unchecked` operators/statements/compiler switches have no effect. Operations with `decimal` values **will always throw an `OverflowException` if the operation can't be performed safely**.